# Xcode 13.3 warning: "'self' refers to the method '{object}.self', which may be unexpected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, warnings, selector

I just updated to Xcode 13.3 and I'm seeing several instances of a new warning that I've not seen with previous versions of Xcode.  As an example, I have a simple table view cell named LabelAndSwitchTableViewCell that looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class LabelAndSwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    private let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    private let _switch: UISwitch = {
        let _switch = UISwitch()
        _switch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        _switch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didToggleSwitch), for: .valueChanged)
        return _switch
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        contentView.addSubview(_switch)

        // layout constraints removed for brevity
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
        
    @objc private func didToggleSwitch() {
        print("Switch was toggled...")
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm adding a target to the switch that I want to be called when the value of the switches changes:

```
_switch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didToggleSwitch), for: .valueChanged)
```

After updating to Xcode 13.3, I'm now seeing a new warning on this line:

```
'self' refers to the method 'LabelAndSwitchTableViewCell.self', which may be unexpected
```

Xcode's suggestion to silence this warning is to replace:

```
_switch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didToggleSwitch), for: .valueChanged)
```

...with...

```
_switch.addTarget(LabelAndSwitchTableViewCell.self, action: #selector(didToggleSwitch), for: .valueChanged)
```

Making this change does silence the warning but it also causes the app to crash (unrecognized selector) when I toggle the switch.  Here's the dump from that crash:

```
[app_mockup.LabelAndSwitchTableViewCell didToggleSwitch]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1043d86e8
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[app_mockup.LabelAndSwitchTableViewCell didToggleSwitch]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1043d86e8'
```

Making the `didToggleSwitch()` method `static` will prevent the crash but I'm not sure why I'd want to do that.  I can obviously revert the change (from `LabelAndSwitchTableViewCell.self` back to just `self`) but I'm wondering if there's something else that I should be doing to address this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can fix by changing the lets to lazy var's

```
private lazy var _switch2: UISwitch = {
    let _switch = UISwitch()
    _switch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    _switch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didToggleSwitch), for: .valueChanged)
    return _switch
}()
```

The Xcode fix-it suggestion is just wrong.

Comment: Hadn't tried making my props lazy vars but you're absolutely right - that does prevent the warning!  Not sure I entirely understand why lazy initing the switch property makes a difference in this particular case but I certainly can't think of a drawback so I will update my code accordingly.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug in 13.3 or if there is some genuine issue about self not being guaranteed to be around, inited and capturable within an auto-evaluating closure

Comment: I think it is possible that in some cases this is a coding error, but warning was never provided until now. (and the warning and correction is confusing at the moment) self is definitely not available when the target is added in this closure, but it also is not needed to be ready in most of the cases. It could happen that the selector event is .allEvents for example, and some event happens before self ready + you need to handle that event. I believe this is a very unlikely scenario that you need an event before self for controls. lazy just make it so that this var will be init after self.

Answer (score 24):

The reason is `self` is not ready yet in phase 1 of object initialisation. Phase 1 is to set all stored properties, and only in phase 2, you can access to `self`.

To fix your code, you can use `lazy` property, where the initialisation phase 1 is completed.

Here is the reference:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html
[image]

For this warning:

1. If there is no super class, or the super class is not `NSObject`, `self` is an error when to use in a stored property directly.
2. If the super class is `NSObject`, `self` gets compiled to an auto closure `(ClassXXX) -> () -> ClassXXX`. So in runtime, self will be used as current instance. But, since Swift 5.6 is warning us on that, I think the reference of self in stored property of a NSObject subclass may not be allowed in future swift versions.

***Example 1: error when there is no super class***
[image]

***Example 2: the compiled self in AST***

For this code:

```
import Foundation
class MyTest: NSObject  {
    var myself = self
}
```

Here is part of the compiled AST:
[image]

Comment: Why then does the target action work at runtime and correctly targets the instance self and not ClassXXX.self

Comment: For now, if a class is a subclass of `NSObject`, the swift compiler will compile `self` into an auto closure: `(ClassXXX) -> () -> ClassXXX` (I have checked both compiled AST and SIL languages, which could confirm the auto closure of `self`). So in runtime, `self` will be used as current instance. But, since Swift 5.6 is warning us on that, I think the reference of `self` in stored property of a `NSObject` subclass may not be allowed in future swift versions.

Comment: Answer is edited to include the AST example

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation!

Answer (score 0):

LabelAndSwitchTableViewCell.self as suggested, will not work in most cases. Use nil and search the responder chain.

[addTarget(_:action:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).